# Add wildcard when code scrabble cheater in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to add a wildcard (one of each character: one * and one ?, total up to twice) to my scrabble rack that can be changed to any single character. If I type bo?*, * and ? should be a~z and all possible words needs to be compared with words in sowpods.txt. How should I edit this code? :) Right now my code works without wildcards. Thanks in advance!

++ when I print the result, it shows like (10, 'bomb'). How can I make it like (10, bomb)? strip or replace didn't work.

```
import sys
import string

scores = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2,
          "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3,
          "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1,
          "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4,
          "x": 8, "z": 10}

# Get the Scrabble rack from the command line.
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("no rack error.")
    exit(1)

rack = sys.argv[1]
rack_low = rack.lower()

# Turn the words in the sowpods.txt file into a Python list.
with open("sowpods.txt","r") as infile:
    raw_input = infile.readlines()
    data = [datum.strip('\n') for datum in raw_input]

# Find all of the valid sowpods words that can be made
# up of the letters in the rack.
valid_words = []

for word in data:
    word_low = word.lower()
    candidate = True
    rack_letters = list(rack_low)
    for letter in word_low:
        if letter not in rack_letters:
            candidate = False
            break # No need to keep checking letters.
        else:
            rack_letters.remove(letter)
    if candidate == True:
        # Get the Scrabble scores for each word.
        total = 0
        for letter in word_low:
            total = total + scores[letter]
        valid_words.append([total, word_low])

# Print the valid words, sorted by Scrabble score.

valid_words.sort(reverse = True)
for entry in valid_words:
    score = entry[0]
    word_low = entry[1]
    print((score, word_low))

print("Total number of words:", len(valid_words))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that all blank tiles are represented by the same character, '*'.  I don't know why you want two different ones, but if you do you can modify my solution appropriately.

Replace your for loop with a function and a shorter for loop (keeping everything else the same):

```
def can_make_word(word):
    rack_letters = list(rack_low)
    for letter in word_low:
        if letter in rack_letters:
            rack_letters.remove(letter)
        elif '*' in rack_letters:
            rack_letters.remove('*') 
        else:
            return False
    return True

for word in data:
    word_low = word.lower()
    if can_make_word(word_low):
        # Get the Scrabble scores for each word.
        total = 0
        for letter in word_low:
            total = total + scores[letter]
        valid_words.append([total, word_low])
```

The single quote marks in your printed output appear because you are printing a tuple.  They aren't characters in your string, so you can't strip them off.  If you rewrite the print statement (removing one set of parentheses) as:

```
print(score, word_low)
```

you will see `10, bomb` in your output instead of `(10, 'bomb')`.  This is because when Python prints a tuple, it formats each element by calling its str() function, which shows strings inside of single quotes.  You can play with this is IDLE or inside an interactive Python session to see how it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :) So if I would like to print it as tuple, there is no way to strip ' ' out from the strings?

Comment: Not that I know of.  You would have to print it element by element, formatting it however you want.  If you found the answer useful please take a moment to accept it.